# Does Hotmail or Outlook.com have a feature where appending a plus sign or a dot to an email address will still have it sent to the same address?

Tags: outlook.com, office-365

Gmail has [this feature](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) where appending a plus ("+") sign or a dot to an email address will still have it sent to the same address. This makes it easier to filter emails sent to you, by checking which email address the email was sent to and then label, star or auto-delete emails based on that.

Yahoo! mail also has a similar feature: [Address Guard,](http://antispam.yahoo.com/addressguard) which uses the dash ("-") sign.

Does Hotmail or Outlook.com have a similar feature? If yes, how does it work?

Comment: That's not really a Gmail feature. It's simply a relatively old RFC specification for email. That not all clients support it is an issue with those clients, not a special feature of Gmail or Outlook.com.

Comment: @Aʟᴇ: By client you mean server...?

Comment: @Mehrdad I suppose I did, but perhaps "service" would have been a better word choice.

Comment: This question has answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/121289/does-exchange-support-disposable-e-mail-addresses

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does Hotmail or Outlook.com have a similar feature?

Yes, Outlook.com has that feature as of this week.

> If yes, how does it work?

This [blog article](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/09/17/can-now-use-email-aliases-outlook-com) explains how it works. It works the same as with Gmail.

*Example*

Say your email address is `myname@outlook.com`.
You can add something with a plus `+` sign.
So, sending an email to `myname+mailinglist_topic_x@outlook.com` will still be delivered to `myname@outlook.com`.

Then you can create a rule with, for example, the filter *To-line contains myname+mailinglist_topic_x@outlook.com* and redirect those emails to another folder.

[image: outlook create rule]
<sub>Image source: http://www.ghacks.net/2013/09/17/can-now-use-email-aliases-outlook-com</sub>

Comment: ... but Outlook in general does not (just tried it).

Comment: and what about hotmail.com domain? the same feature is also activated for that domain or only outlook.com support it?

Comment: I have a Hotmail.com email address and i have used it multiple times with the plus sign. I can confirm that it works

Comment: Does a dot work in the subaddress for Hotmail? E.g. `test+foo.bar@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 3):

Outlook.com allows the creation of email aliases, which is essentially the same as the Gmail and Yahoo features that you mention. Email sent to your aliases will forward to your regular Outlook.com account.

Outlook.com does have limits, though: you can only create up to 5 aliases per year, and you can have a maximum of 15 aliases in total.

[Here is the link to the "Create an email alias" page](http://mail.live.com/?rru=createalias).

And here are some links where you can read more about using Outlook aliases:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/outlook/alias-rename-link-FAQ
- http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-live/outlookcom-tip-email-aliases-143910
- http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-live/outlookcom-tip-email-aliases-part-2-143913

Comment: This is hardly the same thing as gmail plus addressing. With gmail and other services (I use SmarterMail on my dedicated server), I can write for example info+stackexchange@domain.com and essentially provide unique emails for each service I sugnup for. With outlook alias I would have to manually create an alias (and there's a maximum limit) so this is not even comparable.

Comment: This answers only part of the question. What about the same support for hotmail.com addresses? For example `mytest+v1+v2+v3-template@hotmail.com` seems to be refused (this is a fake address, but just to mention the pattern) by an outlook.com server.